# Fixing and pointwise-fixing of a structure in a suqare

Tags: logic, category-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Suppose we have this square in the context of Abstract Elementary Class ${\frak K}=(K,\leq_\frak K)$:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
N_1 @>f_1>> N_3 \\
@A{\preceq_\frak K}AA @AA{f_2}A\\
M_0 @>{\preceq_\frak K}>> N_2
\end{CD}
$$

My question is, what is the relationship among these properties of that square:

(1) the square commutes,

(2) the square fixes $M_0$, and

(3) the square fixes $M_0$ pointwise.

Moreover, what needs to be assumed about $M_0,N_1,N_2,N_3,f_1$ and $f_2$ to make sense of this question in each item (1),(2) and (3) above, respectivelly,besides that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $\preceq_\frak K$-embeddings in $\frak K$?

I'm esp. interested in the difference between (2) and (3). I also think
that (1) is the same as (3),but (2) is different.In fact, I'm not sure what (2) means and how it is different from (3).

Comment: Your commutative diagram isn't compiling.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I can see that it isn't but I do not know why. While writting the question it was OK, but not now.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Can you see the right version now?

Comment: To me, the phrase "The square fixes $M_0$" (pointwise or not) is meaningless. You can talk about a *particular map* of sets fixing a set (pointwise), but not a square.

Comment: OK. What is the difference then fixing $A$ $f:M\to N$ for $A\subseteq |M|$ pointwise from fixing $A$ not pointwise?